# Como criar um GridView dinâmico?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Alguém já criou um `GridView` em que já existam linhas preenchidas com valores e na última coluna de cada linha existe um `LinkButton` "Repetir" e quando esse `LinkButton` for clicado, repete a linha logo abaixo da linha clicada?

Estou usando C#.

Comment: Quando uma resposta resolve seu problema, é aconselhável você aceitar ela. É só clicar no sinal de "check" embaixo dos votos da pergunta. Vai ficar verde. Você e o autor da resposta ganham reputação por isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é perfeitamente possível, mas não é a coisa mais fácil de se fazer. De fato, qualquer coisa para se fazer no Web Forms que não seja diretamente provido pela plataforma tem suas complicações. Como tanto, isso pode ser confuso no princípio. Vou tentar explicar passo a passo.

Primeiramente, na sua `GridView` você deve ter uma `TemplateField` para colocar o botão "Repetir" no `ItemTemplate`.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Repetir" CommandName="Repetir"
            CommandArgument="<%#Container.DataItemIndex %>" />
    </ItemTemplate
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Agora você precisa escutar ao evento RowCommand de sua GridView. Basta adicionar algo como `OnRowCommand="MinhaGridView_RowCommand"` na GridView e criar o método no CodeBehind:

```
protected void MinhaGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Repetir") MinhaGridViewRepetirLinha(e.CommandArgument);
}
```

Agora ao método MinhaGridViewRepetirLinha:

```
protected void MinhaGridViewRepetirLinha(string sLinha)
{
    var numeroDaLinha = int.Parse(sLinha);
    DataSourceDaGridView.Insert(numeroDaLinha, DataSourceDaGridView[numeroDaLinha]);
    MinhaGridView.DataSource = DataSourceDaGridView;
    MinhaGridView.DataBind();
}
```

Note que, para isso, eu usei uma `List<>` como `DataSource` da `GridView`. Eu a mantive usando `ViewState`. Vou te mostrar mais ou menos como implementar.

```
private List<object> _dataSourceDaGridView;
protected List<object> DataSourceDaGridView
{
    get
    {
        return _dataSourceDaGridView ?? (_dataSourceDaGridView = ViewState["Linhas"] as List<object> ?? new List<object>());
    }
    set
    {
        _dataSourceDaGridView = ViewState["Linhas"] = value;
    }
}
```

**EU NÃO TESTEI ESSE CÓDIGO, APENAS BASEEI-O EM UM CÓDIGO QUE JÁ USEI. NÃO COPIE E COLE, OBSERVE O CÓDIGO E O ADAPTE A SUAS NECESSIDADES, E CORRIJA OS POSSÍVEIS ERROS NO CAMINHO.**

Aliás, se algum erro for gritante, por favor me avise para que eu edite minha resposta.

Comment: deu um erro: (O índice estava fora do intervalo. Ele deve ser não-negativo e menor que o tamanho da coleção.
Nome do parâmetro: index)
O erro está ocorrendo dentro do método 'MinhaGridViewRepetirLinha' na linha 'DataSourceDaGridView.Insert(numeroDaLinha, DataSourceDaGridView[numeroDaLinha]);'.
Antes eu não devo preencher 'DataSourceDaGridView' com a consulta que eu utilizei para preencher o meu 'GridView', para que assim ele possa saber abaixo de qual linha ele vai inserir a nova linha?

Comment: Sim, preencha sua DataSource antes de usá-la.

Comment: Funcionou, muitíssimo obrigado!

Comment: @RafaelAmorim Não se esqueça de aceitar a resposta caso ela tenha sido útil para você.